# Issue with creating a shape with inputs for a row, column and a character to fill the shape

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java.util.scanner, shapes

I'm accepting an integer value for the rows and columns, then a String value for the character. If the user enters a value of 5 for the row and 2 for the column with the character "@" the output to the user should be:

@@

@@

@@

@@

@@

The code I have so far is below, where the comment is, is where I can't seem to get the for loop working to create the shape with the inputs entered for the desired amount of rows and columns using the character inputted.

```
import java.util.*;
public class createAShape
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String errorMessage = "Please enter an amount in the range 1 and 25", result = "";
        System.out.print("Enter number of rows: ");
        int r = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        if(r < 1 || r > 25)
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number of columns: ");
            int c = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            if(c < 1 || c > 25)
                System.out.println(errorMessage);
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Enter symbol to use: ");
                String character = in.nextLine();
                //continuing from here
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where *is* your for loop? We can't help you to correct your code if you don't show the code that isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two for loops. An outer for loop to count the rows, and an inner loop to do the printing of a row using the character entered. After you print all the columns of a row, you need to print a new line.

Something like this shold do it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        System.out.print('@');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: That cleared it up, thanks!